# Using Parameters in DATEADD function of a Query

Tags: sql-server, parameters, dateadd

I am trying to us the [DateAdd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function of SQL in my Query. The problem is when I use a parameter to set the second arguement, the *number* argument I get an error which will say something like this:

> Failed to convert parameter value from
>   a Decimal to a DateTime

While if I enter it parameterless, i.e hardcode an Int, it works fine.

This works:

```
SELECT     FieldOne, DateField
FROM         Table
WHERE     (DateField> DATEADD(day, -10, GETDATE()))
```

while this does not:

```
SELECT     FieldOne, DateField
FROM         Table
WHERE     (DateField> DATEADD(day, @days, GETDATE()))
```

Where @days = -10

Any ideas into what I am doing wrong? Incidentally I am setting this variable in SQL Server Manager, as I am trying to work out a bug in my DataAccess code. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Thanks

Comment: works fine for sql server 2008 management studio. Which sql server are you using.

Comment: I suggest giving us closer to the actual code rather than this basic version which nobody can find any problem with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you're passing the decimal as the 3rd instead of the 2nd parameter to `DATEADD()`, like:

```
DATEADD(day, GETDATE(), @days)
```

Although the snippet in the question looks fine.

(For extra clarity, the snippet above is an error. This is the code that would generate the error from the question.)

Comment: The documentation for DATEADD() (and my experience using it) suggests this is inaccurate. This is a bug in SSIS - the above code will not work in any version of SQL. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Comment: @spikeh the above code highlights the snippet that contains the error. Why would you expect it to work?

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old post, but for anyone else having this problem I had a similar issue in Reporting Services 2008 R2, although the error message was "Argument data type nvarchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function." I think this issue could be related.

The problem was caused by the way Reporting Services parses the SQL code to generate a report dataset. In my case, I was able to change this dataset query:

```
SELECT  DateAdd(wk, @NumWeeks, calendar_date) AS ToWeekFromDate
FROM dim_date
```

to this:

```
SELECT  DateAdd(wk, Convert(Int, @NumWeeks), calendar_date) AS ToWeekFromDate
FROM dim_date
```

and the error was resolved.

EDIT: Just to expand on this answer a little: the issue was that Reporting Services was unable to parse the correct data type for `@NumWeeks`, I think possibly due to it being inside the `DateAdd()` function, and was defaulting it to NVarchar. Adding an explicit `Convert()` to set the data type to Int (even though it was already a number) enabled the parser to correctly identify the data type for `@NumWeeks`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works perfectly fine here (SQL Server 2005, executed in Management Studio):

```
DECLARE @days decimal
SET @days = -10

SELECT DATEADD(day, @days, GETDATE())
```

as does the following

```
DECLARE @days decimal
SET @days = -10

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDate > DATEADD(day, @days, GETDATE())
```

So, the problem must lie somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the error is associated with this statement? There are no decimals involved and if I try this it still works

```
DECLARE @days decimal (19,6)
SET @days = -10.3346

--result is actually irrelevant
IF CAST(40000.6 AS decimal (19,6)) > DATEADD(day, @days, GETDATE())
    SELECT 'yes'
ELSE
    SELECT 'no'
```

Even trying to cast -10 decimal to smalldatetime this gives a different error

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(-10 AS decimal (19,6)) AS smalldatetime)

Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type smalldatetime.
```