# nvarchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm currently trying to put this query into Visual Studio

```
DECLARE @StartDate date
SELECT @StartDate = GETDATE();
WITH cte AS 
(
     SELECT -1 AS idx, DATEADD(d,-1,@StartDate) AS idxDate

 UNION ALL
 SELECT idx -1, DATEADD(d,-1,idxDate)
 FROM cte
 WHERE idx >-365
)

SELECT idx DateValue, CONVERT(VARCHAR (11),idxDate,109) + ', ' + CAST
(idx as nvarchar(max)) DateLabel
FROM CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

However I get this error saying

**`nvarchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function`**

Is there something wrong here?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL and Visual Studio 2008 R2

Comment: To confirm, you mean Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2? There never was a "Visual Studio 2008 R2".

Comment: ya sorry about that Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 is what im using

Comment: Can you try changing to `DATEADD(d,Convert(Int, -1),@StartDate)`?  Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10376679/1768890

Comment: yes i did try that, it still giving me the same error >.<

Comment: Your query works fine [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/16970). There must be something else that is giving you the error.

Comment: We'd probably do better if we knew what your overall goal was and then you presented the above as "this is what I have so far". It looks like you're doing something with a years worth of dates (ignoring leap years) that run up until yesterday, but I don't know what you're planning to do with those dates.

Comment: That TSQL runs fine for me.   How are you trying to put it into Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's and old post but this answer will help others as well.

I was facing the same issue with an error message when binding PHP parameters with query the issue was it need type casting the second parameter as it says in error message.

1. `DATEADD(dd, :lifetime_days, GETUTCDATE())`

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function. [20018]
```

2. `DATEADD(dd, :lifetime_days, CONVERT(CHAR(19), GETUTCDATE(), 20))`

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 20018 Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function. [20018]
```

Finally, it works when I have cast the binding parameter to Integer, as lifetime_days is a binding parameter in your case it could be an SQL variable like @time. Sometime it may consider second  parameter as string in that scenario it needs to cast into int.

```
DATEADD(dd, CAST(:lifetime_days AS int), CONVERT(CHAR(19), GETUTCDATE(), 20))
```

Hope it will help you to sort this error message.