# VS Express 2013 Using a parameter in DATEADD results in Failed to convert parameter value from a Decimal to a DateTime

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

This is driving me crazy...

Simply put a user selects a number of weeks from a dropdown list, this value is passed to a variable but as it isn't working I am currently hardcoding the variable:

`Dim Weeks As Integer = -4`

Once I get it working I will set Weeks equal to the combobox's value.

Weeks is then passed to the following part of a Table Adapters SQL (note: I am not adding a parameter via VB code, it is the SQL part of a table adapter in Visual Studio):

`AND DateEntered >= DATEADD(week, CONVERT(INT,@Weeks), GETDATE())`

(I started without the `convert()` but after googling the issue and reading the following:[Using Parameters in DATEADD function of a Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783312/using-parameters-in-dateadd-function-of-a-query?rq=1)
I put the convert in but I still get the error.

I simply (or so I thought) wanted to check for any matching DB rows where DateEntered was in the last e.g. 4 weeks (but wanted that number to be user selected hence the forms combobox). 
If I use "

`AND DateEntered >= DATEADD(week, -4, GETDATE())`

in the SQL it works perfectly. Serves me right for trying to make a user friendly program I suppose.

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated as I have spent several hours trying to get this working and I am running out of hair to pull out.

Many many thanks,
Paul.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it is the SQL part of the table adapter". Can you show us the code where you put the SQL together and use it to fill the dataset/datatable?

Comment: As I said in the post - I am not adding a parameter via VB code, it is the SQL part of a table adapter in Visual Studio. - I am using the visual studio GUI. I have a Table Adapter and that is part of the SQL.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add... The SQL is used to "Fill" the TableAdpter via the line of code:
Me.SageWorksOrdersTA.Fill(Me.ProductionDataSet.SageWorksOrders, Weeks)
Sorry I should have included that code line in the post.

Comment: Ahh, you are using design-time-controls. I think what you are doing may fall outside of the scope for these controls; to use a SQL functions. What about converting the date in vb first? DateTime.Now.AddDays((weeks * 7))

Comment: Hmm. The message sounds like DateEntered is defined as a decimal rather than a date. But I don't see why replacing \@week with a constant would fix that. I tried queries with both the SQL snippets you have above and they both worked as expected for me. What is \@week defined as? I tried a varchar and a decimal and they both worked fine. You might give a larger code excerpt, maybe the error is more complex.

Comment: The DateEntered field I am checking against is defined in the SQL table as "datetime". The Weeks variable I am using is defined as Integer (I think I have also tried it as a decimal).
As a reminder if I replace the @Weeks with -4 or -6 (an actual number) the Fill command works perfectly.

Comment: Sean - Interesting using your method if my Weeks variable equalled 4 (I am wanting to find rows where [DateEntered] >= to the date 4 weeks ago) what would my WHERE DateEntered >= code be? Hey if it works I dont really care whether I use dateaddd or not. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the code-behind sub of getbyweek(..) as LinDataTable? Post that.

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to answer without seeing the code.
I guess there is datetype problem.
Usually a universal way could be to use a reference date like 01/01/2000 and integer field in SQL 
datediff(day,dateentered,'01/01/2000') as datav
then in vbnet 
dim dv as integer=datediff(day,today,'01/01/2000')
and filter the sql table select ... from sqltable where dv>datav-28

Comment: I dont want the user to have to pick a date I wanted them to check against the table for the last x number of weeks.
What code are you missing?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working following the pointer from SEAN. Gave up on using DATEADD as it just would not work. As he said - you are using design-time-controls. I think what you are doing may fall outside of the scope for these controls;

This is how I got around the issue...

Dim WORetrieveDate As String

WORetrieveDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(WeeksComboBox.Text * -1 * 7)
(WeeksComboBox.Text being the Dropdown form box showing the number of weeks to select from and -1 as I want to create a date in the past not future)

Then in the "Fill" SQL statement of my TableAdapter I have

AND DateEntered >= @WORetrieveDate

Now the Date comparison works perfectly. Thanks again to Sean for pointing me in the right direction.